# Requesting a local file with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a mock backend service with my angular 5 application and I want to respond with a picture to a specific request. But I'm stuck at trying to get the picture from a local folder.

I wanted to use fs, but I can't do it on the front-end and I played around with the FileReader and Blob with no success.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
 -- mock-data
 ---- mock-backend
 ------ document-images
 -------- image1.jpg
 -------- image2.jpg
 -- mock-backend-service
```

And I'm working with this method:

```
  getDocumentImage(mockConnection: any, url: string) {
    img = './document-images/00000-P1.jpg';

    // I need a way to get the file here, and send it back
    if (size(img) > 0) {
      mockConnection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(img)
      })));
    } else {
      mockConnection.mockError(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: { error: 'Picture ' + pageNumber + ' does not exist' }
      })));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using webpack to build your JS? If so you could configure the `file-loader` for images and then `import`/`require()` the image file - webpack will build it into the bundle.

Comment: I'm using the webpack implemented by angular-cli. I don't think I can do it this way.

Comment: you respond with a fixed content photo you 'own', why not just put it in the assets directory and call it  via  assets in in angular 5? Why serve the photo from node, if you know the image you are going to send.. Then again I could be reading it wrong, and you - friday tired brain needs beer.

Comment: I think I'll go with that solution since I'm just mocking a solution. It's much better.